# How to dynamically change OpenType features in a TextBox in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, typography, opentype

I'm working on a UWP App that shows some demo texts for some fonts. I want to offer the option to Toggle Ligatures on or off in the demo texts.

As far as I am it works fine with TextBlocks but not with TextBoxes. And I need demo texts to be editable.

My code looks like this:

```
<TextBox
 Typography.StandardLigatures="{Binding ...}"
 Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="{Binding ...}"
 Typography.ContextualLigatures="{Binding ...}"
 Typography.HistoricalLigatures="{Binding ...}"
 Text="This is a demo text fl fi ffl">
```

The Bindings are Boolean properties from a ViewModel attached to some Toggleswitch controls.

The curious thing is that if you change **TextBox** for **TextBlock** it works perfectly.

I know this only works with supported fonts, I'm using compatible typefaces like Palatino which totally support Ligatures.

Please if you know something that I don't let me know

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've reported it to the relevant team. They're investigating it.

Comment: For now, the Typography property is not supported by TextBox in UWP. Please submit a **Feature Request** on [WinUI Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22).

Comment: Thanks @XavierXie-MSFT, it seems RichEditBox don't support it either